# Grouping by and filtering for column value containing string and aggregate function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I group by a couple of columns for only values that contain a string anywhere in that column value?

For example if I want to look at state and theatre name but only look at the count or number of times a title as the word dog anywhere in it how can I group by to filter with that?

```
State | Theatre | Title           | TicketPrice
NY       B        Dog in heaven        5.50
NJ       C        Basketball           3.33
NY       B        Cats                 9.00
NY       B        Hair of Dog          44.00
NY       B        Lions                22.00
NJ       C        Dog Land             4.99
```

Grouping by State and Theatre, I want only the count of titles where Dog as a word appears in the Title column and the sum for each grouped by only for titles where Dog appears?

Thanks!

Comment: `df[df['Title'].str.contains('Dog')].groupby(['State', 'Theatre'])['TicketPrice'].sum()`

Answer (score 2):

Compare column by [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for mask, convert to integers for `True->1` and `False->0` mapping and count number of `1` by `sum`:

```
df1 = (df.assign(count = df['Title'].str.contains('Dog').astype(int))
        .groupby(['State', 'Theatre'])['count']
        .sum()
        .reset_index())

print (df1)
  State Theatre  count
0    NJ       C      1
1    NY       B      2
```

If want also aggregate `sum` for `TicketPrice` column per groups:

```
df2 = (df.assign(count = df['Title'].str.contains('Dog').astype(int))
        .groupby(['State', 'Theatre'])['count', 'TicketPrice']
        .sum()
        .reset_index())

print (df2)
  State Theatre  count  TicketPrice
0    NJ       C      1         8.32
1    NY       B      2        80.50
```

Filter rows and then count number of rows, but if filter out groups with no match:

```
df1 = (df[df['Title'].str.contains('Dog')]
        .groupby(['State', 'Theatre'])['TicketPrice']
        .size()
        .reset_index(name='count'))

print (df1)
  State Theatre  count
0    NJ       C      1
1    NY       B      2
```

Comment: Thanks but had question, in first line, does the  size() function sum up the ticket prices? @jezrael

Comment: @Chris90 - What is expected output?